# Image matching with real objects in iOS

Tags: ios, opencv, image-processing

I have a database of images of various articles and the related information. Am creating an application in which user can scan/click an image of the real object and the application should match that image with the images in the database and identify which object was scanned/clicked by the user.

For example: user scans a fish(catfish for eg.), the application should check the images in the database and tell if it(catfish) is present or not.

I want this implementation in an iOS application.
Am trying to use OpenCV for this, but I cant find proper documentation to how to implement object detection and comparison in iOS.

Any suitable methods or suggestions would be greatly helpful.
Thanks in advance

Comment: https://developer.vuforia.com/resources/sdk/ios try this

Comment: it is a bit complex for what I am trying to do. And mainly focused on augmented reality, you have any other framework than can pretty much detect objects present in the image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are few ways to go about this with OpenCV:

- [Template](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15606231/176769) [matching](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/histograms/template_matching/template_matching.html)
- [Feature Matching with FLANN](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/features2d/feature_flann_matcher/feature_flann_matcher.html)
- [Object Detection with SIFT](http://chrisjmccormick.wordpress.com/2013/01/24/opencv-sift-tutorial/)
- [Object Detection](http://robocv.blogspot.com.br/2012/02/real-time-object-detection-in-opencv.html) [with SURF](http://languagarage.blogspot.com.br/2013/05/opencv-surf-feature-matching.html)

Take a look at [Feature Detection and Description](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/doc/py_tutorials/py_feature2d/py_table_of_contents_feature2d/py_table_of_contents_feature2d.html) for other ideas.

Comment: Thanks, that seems very helpful, What I figured out from your answer is that I want Object Detection using SURF. I hope I can find a way to integrate that into iOS application.

Comment: It's totally possible.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The SURF method would be the one I'll be using. All i have to do now is integrate into iOS,for which I am following some online tutorials and examples. Thank you!!

Comment: @Varij, Just FYI: as far as I remember SURF algorithm is not free for commercial usage.

Comment: @varij, can you able to integrate it in iOS. me also looking for the same functionality. please provide the sample code.