# Qt - Draw on opencv-imshow with mouse after capture from UI doesn't work

Tags: c++, qt, opencv, image-processing, mouseevent

I have this Qt Project where I can capture an Image from WebCam and afterwards draw on it using OpenCV MouseCallbacks (I perform the drawing on the imshow, not the QGraphicsView).
I can capture the Image and display it using my pushbutton, but I can't draw anything (it even crashes after I click on the Image).

Codes:

mainwindow.h

```cpp
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QPixmap>
#include <QGraphicsView>
#include <QGraphicsScene>
#include <QFile>
#include <QFileDialog>
#include <QMessageBox>
#include <QTimer>

#include <opencv2/imgproc.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgcodecs.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/core.hpp>

#include <vector>

QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE
namespace Ui { class MainWindow; }
QT_END_NAMESPACE

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~MainWindow();

     static void DrawScanPoints(int event, int x, int y, int flag, void* param);
     void DrawScanPoints(int event, int x, int y);

private slots:
    void on_pbt_Capture_clicked();

    void on_pbt_Scan_clicked();

public slots:
    void UpdateFrame();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    cv::VideoCapture videoCap;
     cv::Mat liveImage, inputImage;
    bool camRun = true;
};
#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

mainwindow.cpp

```cpp
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    videoCap.open(0);

    QTimer* timer = new QTimer(this);
    connect(timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(UpdateFrame()));
    timer->start(20);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::UpdateFrame()
{
    if(camRun)
    {
        videoCap.read(liveImage);

        QImage image = QImage(liveImage.data, liveImage.cols, liveImage.rows, QImage::Format_RGB888).rgbSwapped();
        QGraphicsScene* scene = new QGraphicsScene(this);
        scene->addPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(image));

        ui->graphicsView->setScene(scene);
        ui->graphicsView->show();
    }
}

void MainWindow::DrawScanPoints(int event, int x, int y, int flag, void* param)
{
    MainWindow* mw = reinterpret_cast<MainWindow*>(param);
    mw->DrawScanPoints(event, x, y);
}

void MainWindow::DrawScanPoints(int event, int x, int y)
{
    if(event & cv::EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN)
    {
        cv::Point pt = cv::Point(x, y);
        cv::circle(inputImage, pt, 10, cv::Scalar(0, 255, 0), 1, cv::LINE_AA);
    }
}

void MainWindow::on_pbt_Capture_clicked()
{
    camRun = false;
    inputImage = liveImage;

    cv::namedWindow("Capture");
    cv::setMouseCallback("Capture", DrawScanPoints, this);

    while(1)
    {
        cv::imshow("Capture", inputImage);
        cv::waitKey(0);
        cv::destroyAllWindows();
    }
}

void MainWindow::on_pbt_Scan_clicked()
{

}
```

main.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"

#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

mainwindow.ui

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>608</width>
    <height>440</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>MainWindow</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralwidget">
   <widget class="QGraphicsView" name="graphicsView">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>10</x>
      <y>10</y>
      <width>501</width>
      <height>391</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QPushButton" name="pbt_Capture">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>520</x>
      <y>10</y>
      <width>81</width>
      <height>20</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string>Capture</string>
    </property>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QPushButton" name="pbt_Scan">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>520</x>
      <y>40</y>
      <width>80</width>
      <height>18</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string>Scan</string>
    </property>
   </widget>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QMenuBar" name="menubar">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>0</x>
     <y>0</y>
     <width>608</width>
     <height>17</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QStatusBar" name="statusbar"/>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

Comment: Did removing `waitKey` and `destroyWindow` help?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not able to reproduce this locally (I'm missing some of the source files, e.g. main and the UI) but probably you should pass `this` in `setMouseCallback` as the last parameter. See [How should I pass a pointer-to-member-function to setMouseCallback in OpenCV?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37793389/how-should-i-pass-a-pointer-to-member-function-to-setmousecallback-in-opencv)

**Edit after question was updated:**

Remove `cv::destroyAllWindows` from `on_pbt_Capture_clicked`; replace `cv::waitKey(0);`  with `cv::waitKey(30);`:

```
void MainWindow::on_pbt_Capture_clicked()
{
    camRun = false;
    inputImage = liveImage;

    cv::namedWindow("Capture");
    cv::setMouseCallback("Capture", DrawScanPoints, this);

    while(1)
    {
        cv::imshow("Capture", inputImage);
        cv::waitKey(30);
    }
}
```

Reason: you've never updated the "capture" window: `waitKey(0)` waits forever (for any key input) - so your window will be updated with circles only after you press any key on the keyboard. So if you change to `waitKey(30)` the updates will be happening every 30 [ms] automatically (timeout after which `waitKey` exits).

No need to destroy and recreate window every time hence removing `destroyAllWindows`. If you want to be smart about when to update the window in `on_pbt_Capture_clicked`, use conditional variable. WAit for it inside `while(1)` and `notify_one` it from inside `DrawScanPoints`.

Comment: It now detects my clicks, however the circle are only shown after I try to close the imshow (I can't close it completely because of the while loop). I also edited the question above.